# App crashes after adding <Picker> component

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, native

so I am building React Native app and my app crashes only after I add Picker component.

INFO:
PC OS: Windows |||
Emulator: Android (Android Studio)

This is code for my component:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Picker, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class PickerComponent extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <Picker>
                <Picker.Item/>
            </Picker>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    pickerBox: {
        width: "100%",
    }

})

export default PickerComponent;
```

So if you need more info or some logs file please tell me where to find them and I'll send it.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you gone through official docs? They mentioned working example and information regarding same.

Comment: before asking question do some research. Have look here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html#docsNav
Problem is with Picker items

Comment: Could you please provide us the error?

Comment: Ok so, I just ran the app too soon, <Picker.Item/> has to have some props so it crashed, there were no errors so I was bit confused, but thanks for the effort guys!

Comment: Try to add label and value to Picker.Item